# Bind value of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can i execute custom function when some properties of html tag is changed?

For example:

HTML code

```
<a id="link1">title</a>
<a id="link2">title</a>
```

When we change link2 text i want to change link1 text. So i want something like DataBinding in Windows Presentation Foundation.

---

We are changing link2: $('#link2').text('blablablaballba'); and value of link1 must be "blablablaballba". I dont want to write additional code $('#link1').text('blablablaballba'); and so on. link1 must be changed automatically.

Comment: Post your code for changing the link2 text.

Comment: show us how you gonna change Link2 text

Comment: I think it's **way** more cumbersome *and* costly to use such an algorithm than just adding `$('#link1').text('blablablaballba');`

Comment: I dont think there's such concept of "binding values" in JS as there is in WPF

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
$('#link2, #link1').text('blablablaballba');
```

Comment: Why? Because it's not the only place where `#link2` is modified?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a periodic interval to check the contents, like:

```
var timerID;

function watchLink2() {
    var el = document.getElementById("link2");

    return function () {
        if (el.innerHTML != "title") {
            document.getElementById("link1").innerHTML = el.innerHTML;
            clearInterval(timerID);
        }
    };
}

timerID = setInterval(watchLink2(), 200);
```

But, er..., how do you think the attribute's value is changed?

Comment: @Neir0: Then what is it you want? As I stated in my comment above, the easiest way is to use something like manji proposed. Why don't you want to use that?

Comment: Because link1 is changing from jquery plugin.

Comment: @Neir0: can't you let that plugin change `#link1`, too (e.g., by modifying the plugin)? Otherwise you're stuck to this ugly hack.

Comment: Yes. I can modify plugin but it take a lot of time.